# Export range as XML without a file extension

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I can export an excel sheet range as .xml.  However, I want to save without the .xml extension.

I managed to do it before, but lost it again.

```vb
Sub CREATEXML()

Dim Password As String
Do Until Password = "away"
    Password = InputBox("ARE YOU SURE???" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Please enter password below", "Processing...", "????")
    If Password = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XML").Activate
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
FileName =  Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=AUTHORISESEPA.ValDtAUTHFILE.Value & "TESTING.xml", FileFilter:="XML Data(*.xml),*")

If FileName = False Then 
      Exit Sub
End If
Sep = ""
If Sep = vbNullString Then

End If
Debug.Print "FileName: " & FileName, "Separator: " & Sep
ExportToTextFile FName:=CStr(FileName), Sep:=CStr(Sep), _
   SelectionOnly:=True, AppendData:=True
End Sub
```

I should end up with `1111112.21012014TESTING`, not `1111112.21012014TESTING.xml`

This is where the issue is:

```vb
FileName =  Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=AUTHORISESEPA.ValDtAUTHFILE.Value & "TESTING.xml", _
    FileFilter:="XML Data(*.xml),*")
```

Comment: I would rather suggest to save file as xml and next rename it without extension using `Name OldName.XML As OldName`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line you mention, you're adding "TESTING.xml".

```
FileName =  Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:=AUTHORISESEPA.ValDtAUTHFILE.Value & "TESTING.xml", _
FileFilter:="XML Data(*.xml),*")
```

just remove ".xml" there:

```
FileName =  Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:=AUTHORISESEPA.ValDtAUTHFILE.Value & "TESTING", _
FileFilter:="All files,*")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  When I do this, it creates a Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error.

Pointing to my macro call within the form:

Sheet4.CREATEXML